# How to add AoT metadata to non-class, non-component exports?

Tags: angular

I need to export a config object

config.ts

export const CONFIG = { ... }

then reference it in app.module.ts. Upon compilation, angular 2 throws this error

ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported

How can I manually add metadata to config.ts in this case?

Comment: did you ever find a fix for the above problem? I've ran into the same issue as well so.